# JavaFX: manipulate UI at runtime and save changes

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm currently working on a JavaFX project. I use Scene Builder to build the UI. It will include a View with different charts. I want to give the user the possibility to create new charts and configure them at runtime. That's pretty easy. I stuck at the point how to save the  newly created charts so that the user has his configured view when he restarts the application.

I think that I will have to update the FXML-File when creating a new chart a runtime. But I don't know how to do that.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: That's tricky and probably too broad for a StackOverflow question.  The saving as FXML part is addressed in: [Save JavaFX scene into FXML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284904/save-javafx-scene-into-fxml-file), [Saving user interface into fxml : javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874110/saving-user-interface-into-fxml-javafx/30730214) and [JavaFX read and save GUI elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415240/javafx-read-and-save-gui-elements).  None of which have adequate solutions, so your question is unlikely to get one here either.

Comment: This may help you: [JavaFX 8 Tutorial - Part 5: Storing Data as XML](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part5/).

Comment: @jewelsea this looks quite interesting. I will try this and give you feedback. Thanks!